# How to change size of google recaptcha using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

Hi I inserted the Google Recaptcha into my page, I need to change the size as little bit bigger.
I got the answer in css transform method its work but not support Firefox browser, It support chrome browser only.

```
.recaptScale {
    transform:scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

I need a css code for change the size of recaptcha and that support all browsers please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA Resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594842/no-captcha-recaptcha-resizing)

Comment: If you want to supporting `transform` in old version of firefox, use `-moz` before `transform` like `-moz-transform:scale()`. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS `transform:scale()` to changing size of google recaptcha element.

**Normal size:**

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="a"></div>
```

**Small size:**

```css
.recaptScale {
    transform:scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha recaptScale" data-sitekey="a"></div>
```

**Large size:**

```css
.recaptScale {
    transform:scale(2);
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha recaptScale" data-sitekey="a"></div>
```