# How to resize the Invisible RECAPTCHA Image Select Pop Up Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have recently added Google RECAPTCHA V2 INVISIBLE version onto my site.

The problem I have is that the Pop-Up Frame that appears is HUGE on the screen.

Now.. I am not talking about the "I'm Not A Robot" box (all answers I have found on the net seem to talk about scaling this little grey box). So not this one

[image: so not this one]

I am talking about the actual Image Select Pop-Up Frame where you have to click the images... This one. This silly thing;

[image: This silly thing]

The issue I have is not specific to mobile... It even looks HUGE on my laptop.

The common answer that I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594842/no-captcha-recaptcha-resizing#28932845) but this does not change the size of the pop-up image select window. I have played with this and tried all kinds of combinations but nothing works.

I have this invisible RECAPTCHA on a simple form field for people to register for our E-Newsletter. I wanted to validate the HTML5 Form Fields first then on submit call the RECAPTCHA...

I found a great bit of script for this on here (thanks to the person who previously submitted that answer) which works like a charm.

So, here is my complete code..

```js
var renderGoogleInvisibleRecaptcha = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; ++i) {
    var form = document.forms[i];
    var holder = form.querySelector('.recaptcha-holder');
    if (null === holder) {
      continue;
    }

    (function(frm) {

      var holderId = grecaptcha.render(holder, {
        'sitekey': 'site key',
        'size': 'invisible',
        'badge': 'bottomright',
        'callback': function(recaptchaToken) {
          HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(frm);
        }
      });

      frm.onsubmit = function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.execute(holder);
      };

    })(form);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderGoogleInvisibleRecaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<div class="news-container">
  <form action="../php_scripts/handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="news-title">
      Subscribe to our Monthly E-Newsletter
    </div>

    <div class="news-input">
      <div class="field-icon"><i class="fi-mail"></i></div>
      <input class="input" name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter A Valid Email Address')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
    </div>
    <div class="recaptcha-holder"></div>

    <div class="news-submit">
      <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I know it is possible to size this pop-up as I have seen sites in the past that have lovely small pop-up windows for image select, how can I do so?

Comment: can we have a link to the actual page, on wich it looks "huge"?

Comment: Hi Islam... I am using Invisible RECAPTCHA V2 - So when somebody clicks on the send button then the Image Select box pops up

Comment: Hey! I can't seem to get it to work on your website, what am I missing? I tried entering an email and submitting it, and the email was sent without any recaptcha poping :)

Comment: i can't seem to reproduce the problem either

Comment: i've tested in 2 browsers, with vpn, with proxy, i tried spamming it. but i can't get the image box to appear

Comment: Hi Ramon... I do not understand how you are doing that. How can you bypass the RECAPTCHA? Do you have Java disabled? Would that cause a bypass?

Comment: no, i have javascript enabled but what ever i try. no recaptcha, last thing i can check is tor browser, normally every recaptcha always fires on tor due to "looking like a robot"

Comment: I have included a screen shot in the question

Comment: ok, so on tor i do get the image box, just like the one in the screenshot

Comment: Great..!!! So how do I make it smaller?

Comment: I have the same issue, how does the div get appended in the dom and how do I add an id or something to target it with css and scale it down

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution for your problem, in the screen shot below there is a `div` with an `iframe` inside of it,

you should add this pierce of css to the `div` above the `iframe`, and you can also change the `scale` value to make it bigger/smaller:

```
transform: scale(0.77);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.77);
```

Comment: Ramon.. Thank you for your answer. I tried what you suggested (albeit that I did not understand what the iFrame was for or how it worked).. But sadly it did not change the size of the Image Pop-up window. All that it effects is the "RECAPTCHA Badge" in the bottom right corner.. The same thing is true if you add styling to the <div class="recaptcha-holder"></div>

Comment: hmm interesting

Comment: can you put the change you did live, so i can see what happens on the site?

Comment: I am playing with your answer again... What is the iFrame for? How does this work with RECAPTCHA V2? And how does the iFrame work with my original code snipet (see the original question above).. Sorry... But I just cannot get my head round what this iFrame is doing

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UK8K4lD take a look at these screen shots. this is what i see when i execute my solution

Comment: the iframe is an html webpage inside your webpage, google uses this to create the full website overlay with the popup with `select all images` inside of it, within an iframe you open the `<html>` again so they can add their own `<link>, <script>` and other stuff inside. making it possible to include their own scripts and keep it updated without you in need to update anything. also take a look here for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: the div wich now contains `transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin 0 0: ;` instead of `transform: scale(0.77);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.77);` + i think there is a `display:block` on that same div, remove that or add `display:none`

Comment: yes, that's because the div around the `iframe` still misses `transform: scale(0.77); -webkit-transform: scale(0.77);`

Comment: add this in your javascript file: `$(document).ready(function(){
 $('iframe[name="c-tdq9i7hgymlb"]').parent().css({
  'transform' : 'scale(0.77)',
  '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(0.77)'
  });
});` and make sure you have jquery lib installed

Comment: This is very close to an answer... But when I call grecaptcha.execute(holderId) in the Java this will overwite anything in the iframe we added.. I am playing with the java to try and put the scaling (transform) in their but at the moment cannot find a way to effect the image pop-up

Comment: You was really really close with this answer Ramon.. It gave me the clue to fix it.. I will update my original question with the right answer.. Thank you very much for your suggestions and helping me find the solution..!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem was easier than I could envisage.. Special thanks to Ramon for giving me the clue that resulted in the answer.

I added one line of code to the Java immediately after the execute recaptcha function

$('iframe').parent().css({ 'transform' : 'scale(0.77)', '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(0.77)' });

When the iframe loads it is then scaled according to the parameters given. This solved the visual appearance issue I had with the Image Select iframe pop-up. I guess this could be taken further and used to create a dynamic scaling for mobiles, but the 0.77 does for what I needed.

The only draw back to this solution is that once the execute recaptcha function has been called it will scale EVERY iframe on the page. I tried to find a fix that just scaled the recaptcha iframe but failed to do so.

So, here is the final fully functioning Java code. This will validate the form fields using HTML5 methods, then call the recapcha which can now be scaled as described above.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var renderGoogleInvisibleRecaptcha = function() {
 for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; ++i) {
 var form = document.forms[i];
 var holder = form.querySelector('.recaptcha-holder');
 if (null === holder){
 continue;
 }

 (function(frm){

 var holderId = grecaptcha.render(holder,{
 'sitekey': 'Your Site Key',
 'size': 'invisible',
 'badge' : 'bottomright', // possible values: bottomright, bottomleft, inline
 'callback' : function (recaptchaToken) {
 HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(frm);
 }
 });

 frm.onsubmit = function (evt){
 evt.preventDefault();
 grecaptcha.execute(holderId);
 $('iframe').parent().css({ 'transform' : 'scale(0.77)', '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(0.77)' });
 };

 })(form);
 }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: This will work but this is so hugly, I am looking for something more elegent, is there a way to name the iframe or it's container ?